# PHP.ini error -- No permission -- Root User

Tags: php, macos, apache, ini

Trying to setup and configure my mac as a testing server. So setting up the php.ini, i get an error when trying to save my changes:

```
Error writing /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini: Permission denied
```

I don't know why this happened or how to fix it (noob)
-I am logged in as root.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this,

```
sudo -i

nano /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

OR

```
sudo  nano /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

OR

```
vi  /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

Comment: THANKS, your edit worked. Now do you know why I maybe did not have permission the first time? @ChinnuR

Comment: sudo -i

nano /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

Comment: Some system files aren't available for just anyone (or any program) to change or delete. For such cases you need to act as the root user, or superuser. Usually this means typing "sudo" before the command and it will ask you for a password. This will allow you to do something as the superuser.

Comment: Thanks, I just found this strange because I thought I was the root user. Im logged in as admin on my own personal mac

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sudo chmod 644 /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

It will give you the rights to write on the php.ini

Comment: did you restart apache?